# Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string' in .tsx file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I have this problem to add form element in tsx file.

```
import { AuthLayout } from "../layout/AuthLayout"

export const LoginPage = () => {
       return (
      <AuthLayout title='Login'>

        <form>
          
          bla bla bla

        </form>

      </AuthLayout>
    ) }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSZph.png)

Comment: Don't post errors as images. Also the problem seems to be in the AuthLayout component, please include the code for that

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Most likely AuthLayout is expecting a child of type string, but you're passing it a form instead.

Comment: Yes Eduardo, AuthLayout expected type string

export const AuthLayout = ({ children = '', title=''}) => {

What type could you put on the children, that fixed this error?

Comment: @geradeluxer so then that's your problem. You'll need to change the type for children

Comment: Thank you Brian, i solved the problem with this export const AuthLayout = ({ children, title=''}: any) => {

Comment: If you're going to type as `any` you might as well stop using TS

Comment: :( What type could you put on the children? i understand the LoginPage return "JSX.Element" but i don't know how wich one to put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the AuthLayout component is expecting a child of type `string`, but you're passing it a `form` instead.

You should change it so that children can be more flexible than that, accepting not only string but also (single or multiple) HTML element(s) and React component(s). You can do that by typing children with `React.ReactNode`.

```js
export const AuthLayout = ({
  children,
  title,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  title: string;
}) => {
  // ...
};
```

*Typing it is as `any`, like you mentioned in your comment, is not recommended, as it eliminates the main advantage of TypeScript, which is ensuring correct typing during development, before runtime.

Comment: That's a better solution and it's clearer to me, i could create a constant type to have clean code.
Thank you very much Eduardo!